# Amazon Route 53 Forward Subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, amazon-route53

I bought a domain from GoDaddy, say **abc.com**.

I was able to forward **profile.abc.com** to **http://www.linkedin.com/in/myname**.

Not I've changed my domain nameserver to Amazon Route 53, I want to do the same thing but wasn't able to do so, here's what I've tried:

Create a new record set, name is **profile.abc.com**, type is **CNAME**, value is **http://www.linkedin.com/in/myname**.

But this doesn't work.

I have another CNAME, hg.abc.com, which points to my BitBucket (value = www.bitbucket.com), that one works.

Comment: @Adam no, the CNAME as presented in the question definitely cannot work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the CNAME record cannot be a URL. It must point to another name in the DNS, just like `hg.abc.com` does.

It sounds like what you want to do is host a web site at `profile.abc.com` which redirects all incoming requests to `http://www.linkedin.com/in/myname`. If so, that's exactly what you should do:

1. Set up a web server somewhere (e.g. Apache)
2. Configure it to redirect all incoming requests (e.g. using Apache's `Redirect` directive)
3. Either:

   - Install a CNAME record for `profile.abc.com` that points to the canonical name of the server that hosts the web site, OR
   - Install A and AAAA records for `profile.abc.com` that give the IP addresses of the server that hosts the web site.

Comment: Are there good redirect service provider I can use rather than setup my own web server (while still use route 53 as my dns)? Thanks!

Comment: @DerekLi - this answer is probably too late to help, but for anyone else, Amazon S3 is now a good simple (and cheap) option for this http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html